# Order of a prime modulo another prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p,q$ be primes such that $q \equiv 1 \mod{p}$.

Are there any necessary/sufficient conditions for the order of $p \in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ to be divisible by $p$?

I know this doesn't always hold (e.g. $p=5, q=31$), but can't figure out when it should.

Comment: When $p=2$ there are some such conditions: if $q\equiv3\pmod4$ then it is necessary and sufficient that $q\equiv7\pmod8$. (This is a special case of quadratic reciprocity.) You might be able to get similar conditions out of cubic reciprocity (when $p=3$) or quartic reciprocity (when $p=2$ and $q\equiv1\pmod4$), but things get complicated really quickly. In general, whether the order of $p$ modulo $q$ is divisible by $p$ is likely to be essentially random.